# UV distortion. Help

Tags: texturing, uv

been facing some peculiar problem lately when I was unwrapping UV.

The UVs are fully "flat" and does seem to have any distortion. However, as you can see form the image. The checker looks completely distorted. I checked for stretching and It seem decent with no serious distortion. Hence,  I have no idea what causes
it.

Further information:

- I use the add-on UV square to unwrap the UV
- the checker are from the add-on Texel Density.

[image][image] [image: it.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.  The distortion is cause by the double UV maps in the Object properties Tap. Once I deleted the unwanted map. everything went back to normal.

[image]

[image]